# How to add Html.AntiForgeryToken to ActionLink and RedirectToAction?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with adding AntiForgeryToken. This is my code:

```
<%:Html.ActionLink("Text", "Action", new { ID = "Hello")})%>
```

and

```
 RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller", new { ID = "HelloFromMe"});
```

Controller:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Action(String ID){
return View();
}
```

Does anybody have idea how to do it ?

Comment: Why do you want to use a AntiForgeryToken in a GET method?

Comment: Because the ID that i pass correspond to key in TempData. I want the request to contain verification token (even a get request).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to use an AntiForgeryToken into a GET method.

GET methods should only be used for read-only operation on your server. If you want to do something else than a read-only operation, then, you should use a POST method.

Here the reason why this token is useful, how and when to use it. http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/02/anatomy-of-csrf-attack.aspx

Comment: Okay.Thank you for the response :)

Comment: I've added a link explaining the see-surf attacks (CSRF)

Comment: So instead of nice link buttons like "Delete" or "Hide" we should switch to ugly form posts? It is totally OK to use links, at least for avoiding "Do post form again" problem when going back and forth. Native ValidateAntiForgeryToken will not work for links, but custom one will work just fine.

Comment: @ADOConnection don't you know about javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of antiforgery token is to prevent attacker to generate POST / GET request on behalf of the user. Thats why we add something special to every POST / GET request, that is unknown to attacker.

The simplest implementation of custom antiforgery would look like this.
And it will be exactly safe as ValidateAntiForgeryToken.

```
public class ProfileController : AuthorizedAccessController
{
    // GET
    public ActionResult Details(int userId)
    {
        User user = this.Entities.User.First(u => u.Id == userId);

        this.Session["ProfilePageAntiforgery"] = Guid.NewGuid(); // use RandomNumberGenerator to generate strong token 
        this.ViewBag.ProfilePageAntiforgery = this.Session["ProfilePageAntiforgery"];

        return View(user);
    }

    public ActionResult DeleteMyProfile(int userId, string profilePageAntiforgery)
    {
        if ((string)this.Session["ProfilePageAntiforgery"] != profilePageAntiforgery)
        {
            return this.RedirectToAction("Details", new { userId });
        }

        User user = this.Entities.User.First(u => u.Id == userId);
        this.Entities.User.Remove(user);

        this.Entities.SaveChanges();

        return this.RedirectToAction("ProfileDeleted");
    }
}
```

View:

```
<div>
     @Html.ActionLink("Delete my profile", "DeleteMyProfile", new {userId = this.Model.Id, profilePageAntiforgery = this.ViewBag.ProfilePageAntiforgery })
</div>
```

Making custom attributes out of this is a matter of technique.
Lets say one attribute to store token in session and viewbag and the other to validate.

If using Session is not OK (Web farm etc.) you can simply replace it by DB or other store.